# Jquery scroll check doing opposite of what I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

So all I want is for jquery to check weather the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page and then do something if they have.. 
But strangely enough it's doing the opposite, it'll alert when I scroll to the top, and not the bottom, any idea why this is? Am I looking at it and not seeing it?

Here is my code so far:

```
 <script>
     $(window).scroll(function() {   
         if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            var img_no = $(".imgcontain").length;
            alert("There are "+img_no+" images on the page.");
     }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3T4K/ well, the code works fine to me?

Comment: works good for me http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/8gTDx/

Comment: Works as expected... http://jsfiddle.net/8pftj/

Comment: what browser/ os are you using Alex?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've done the stupidest thing, but I might as well confess in case others ever have the same problem.

I forgot the !DOCTYPE html.

Yup, it was really that stupid of me.